# Getting all the rows from the table in addition with min and max value

Tags: mysql, codeigniter-3

I want to get all the rows in addition to two columns which will be max and min value from the same table. The above query gives me only min value and max value from the table price but i have to get all the rows from price table.

```
$this->db->select('MAX(price) as max_package_price, MIN(price) as min_package_price,user_id as user_id');
    $results = $this->db->get($this->price)->result();

price   title    date
------------------------

500    P1     2019-12-31
700    P2     2019-09-15
400    P3     2019-08-14
```

i want to get lowest price and highest price with all the rows from the table in one query.

Comment: share the sample data and expected data.

Comment: This is not how MySQL works - there is no way to get both aggregated values and full rows

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is *yes it is possible* but its probably not the best way to do it (I believe this solution will place more work on your DB queries - which if they're not optimised could be quite expensive (in terms of time/CPU)).

`$this->db->select('price,title,date,(SELECT MAX(price) FROM '.$this->price.') as MinPrice,(SELECT MIN(price) FROM '.$this->price.') as MaxPrice);`